# How to release submodules with different version numbers with Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-deploy-plugin

In my current maven project I have a lot of submodules. I need to build a release and deploy it to my nexus...

Now I am facing the challange that I need for some of the modules differing version numbers. How can I handle this by usage of the release & deploy plugin? Or do I need some other maven plugins??? I configured the release plugin inside the parant pom. Is there a possibility to disable for example the "autoVersionSubmodules" for some of the submodules? Any ideas???

Comment: Has that happended before? or is this the first time having different versions for different modules?

Comment: Yes, but originally the release/build process was done via shell script. Now I want to change the release process.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a multi-module build than all modules should have the same version number otherwise it's an indicator that the multi-module build is not the right choice.

Comment: The project consists of a large number of mudules which are used/combined in 4 assemblies. Each assembly should get it's own version. Should I perform the release process for each of the assemblies? How can I release the different components with different versions?

Comment: I would suggest to extract those assemblies into a different project which will solve the problem.

Comment: I already have a assembly project with a ressource folder and pom.xml for each of the 4 assemblies. Each folder contains the assembly descriptor XML file. I am not sure how to release the assemblies? Should I call "mvn release:prepare" for each assembly?